# Откат к последнему коммиту

Tags: git

Допустим мне нужно вернуться в нижний коммит, откатился 4 коммита

```
git checkout 27237f0
```

затем мне нужно вернуться на самый последний коммит, на тот который был изначально, вопрос: а как я узнаю с помощью  git log или git log --pretty=oneline хэш, ведь я нахожусь на откатившимся последнем
коммите, а мне узнать нужно хэш-сумму самого последнего

Comment: `git reflog` показывает историю изменения. Из `man git-reflog`: Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуться к последнему коммиту можно без хэш-суммы:

```
git checkout имя-ветки
```

Например:

```
git checkout master
```

**Upd.** ([нашел тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263674/how-do-i-find-the-next-commit-in-git-child-children-of-ref)) А чтобы получить список всех коммитов после того, на который сделан откат, можно сделать так:

```
git log --reverse --ancestry-path хэш-сумма^..имя-ветки
```

Или

```
git log --reverse --ancestry-path HEAD^..имя-ветки
```

Comment: а если мне надо на откатившимся  коммите остаться, и не хочу  возвращаться на остальные 4 коммита выше, как бы я хочу их просто проигнорировать или якобы избавиться от них, как быть???

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Сделав чекаут коммит вы и так на том коммите.

Comment: просто когда делаю 
`git checkout some-branch`  
я сразу же возвращаюсь на 4 коммита выше, на том котором был изначально

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос на эту тему.